# Evaluating the convergence of $\int_{(1, +\infty)}\frac{1}{x \log x \ e^x}$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, asymptotics, riemann-integration

I'm reading a proof where the integral over $(1,+\infty)$ of the function $$(1, +\infty)\ni x \mapsto f(x)=\frac{1}{x \log x \  e^x}$$ is shown to be $+\infty$ by invoking the fact that if $f,g$ are continuous positive functions with $f \sim g$ (i.e. f is asymptotically equivalent to g) and the integral of $g$ diverges over the domain, the so does the integral of f.

Now, the proposed solution gives the estimates
$$\frac{1}{x \log x \  e^x}= \frac{e^{-x}}{x \log x } \sim \frac{e^{-1}}{\log(1+x-1)} \sim \frac{e^{-1}}{x-1}=\frac{1}{e(x-1)}$$
and then 
$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e(x-1)}=\frac{1}{e}\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(x-1)}=\frac{1}{e}\log(x-1)_{|_1^{+\infty}}=+\infty$$

**Question**

> I do not understand the estimates above.

Comment: In ii) I think you get $\infty+\infty$  In i) do your realize that they looking at the behavior near $x=1$?

Comment: @saulspatz in ii) you are right and I will edit. I realize that they plug 1 for $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=e^{-x}$ but i do not understand why this is useful for giving those estimates. If i compute the ratio of the first two functions for example i get $0$ for $x \to +\infty$

Comment: But there's no problem at $\infty$.  The only convergence question comes at $x=1$.  You ned to look at the limit as $x\to1$.

Comment: @saulspatz I do not understand.

Comment: @saulspatz they should be asymptotic for $x \to \infty$ too to use that strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an improper integral to converge, the limit must exist at both endpoints.  In this instance there is no problem with the endpoint at $\infty$. When $x>2$ say, the integrand positive and bounded above by $e^{-x}$, so the integral is  less than $\int_2^\infty e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x=e^{-2}$.  When $x\to1+$ the integrand goes to $\infty$.  So the questions comes down to investigating the behavior of $\int_t^2f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ as $t\to1+$

The asysmptotic behavior the proof talks about is as $x\to1+$.

Comment: It does not make any sense to choose a function that dominates $f$ after $2$ for proving that $\int f > +\infty.$ What one should do, instead, is notice that $f>0 $ for $x>1,$ so that for any $M>1$ we have $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x \log x \  e^x} \geq \int_1^M \frac{1}{x \log x \  e^x} \ dx + 0 $ and then one can compute $\int_1^M \frac{1}{x \log x \  e^x} \ dx \geq \frac{1}{e^M} \log(\left|\log(M)\right|)-\log(\left|\log(1)\right|)= +\infty.$ But then there is no need to use that asymptotic estimates at all, so what am I missing?

Comment: @jobbalobba My point is that only the behavior near $x=1$ matters.  Your question and comments seemed to be concerned with the behavior at $\infty$, which is irrelevant.  As for the present comment, it should have been part of your question.  How could you expect anyone to guess this is what you were asking? But yes, this shows that the integral diverges.

Comment: you are right, my bad. but I was confused by your mention of $e^{-x}$. Now I think everything is clear.